# List visible databases in Teradata SQL Assistant?

Tags: sql, teradata

I am working w the Teradata SQL Assistant. What I am trying to do, is to list all databases visible in the 'Database Explorer'. At first, I have tried simple query:

```
select DatabaseName from DBC.Databases;
```

but this returned thousands of databases I don't even have an access to. The DBC.Databases table seems not to have any field allowing me to filter results to only visible databases, or I am just unable to find it. And I am almost sure there is no such field in any table like '%database%'.

Is there any way to list those visible databases with SQL query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Never use a system view without a trailing `V` or `VX`, those are old legacy views which will truncate object names over 30 characters.

In your case you need to switch to `dbc.DatabasesVX`, the `X` indicates that all objects where you don't have any access right are filtered automatically. But this might still return more databases than Database Explorer where you can add databases to the list manually.

Comment: This shows just 36 DBs, which is almost acceptable, if there is no possibility to filter everything not visible. Thank you.

Comment: If you wanted to filter on specific permissions for a specific user or role you could join to DBC.ALLRIGHTSV and/or DBC.ALLROLERIGHTSV and filter on a specific permission associated with a user/role for that database.  It gives you more control than just using the VX view but might not be worth the effort for a small difference

Comment: If you are looking for the databases visible in your SQL-Assistant, you can't find it in the database, that information is stored within your SQL-Assistant.